# Showing Excel File Data in Editor Using Python Django Framework

Tags: python, django, excel, editor

I want to show the Excel File Data in Editor using django framework, python.
If anybody knows how to do this, please help me. I am new in django framwork

Comment: This is much too broad. I suggest you go through some django tutorials to get you to the point you can be specific with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you [Django-Excel](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)